# Multi value select not binding List in Spring MVC 3

Tags: spring-mvc

we are trying to bind a list of model with the multi select true in the select box.

```
private List<Isic> isices = new LinkedList<Isic>();
```

In the Model this the list of isices that we need to map to the multi select box.

```
<form:select  path="isices" multiple="true" >   
<form:options items="${primaryIsic}"  itemLabel="isicClassName" 
      itemValue="isicClassCode"/>
</form:select>
```

In controller when I try to fetch the value of isices it return me alist with size 0.
What am I doing wrong here.

Comment: Make sure you have a converter/editor and make sure that you have a proper equals/hashcode implementation.

Comment: converter/editor ??
Are you talking about InitBinder ?